# How to prove that the Fibonacci sequence $7\mid U_m\Longrightarrow 8\mid m$ and $4\mid U_m\Longrightarrow 6\mid m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

How to prove that the Fibonacci sequence $$7\mid U_m\Longrightarrow 8\mid m$$ and $$4\mid U_m\Longrightarrow 6\mid m$$I was confused because there $\{ 4,7 \}$ in Fibonacci sequece

Comment: You have asked several questions on divisibility of Fibonacci numbers already, like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468439/two-issues-of-number-theory) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468479/divisibility-and-the-fibonacci-sequence/468561#468561) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468346/statement-on-the-fibonacci-sequence). What have you learnt?

Comment: @CalvinLin Many things. Thank you;) Happy

Comment: Please ask a new question instead of editing the current one into something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60340/fibonacci-modular-results), $$(F_m,F_n)=F_{(m,n)}\implies F_m|F_n\iff m|n$$

Now, the smallest Fibonacci number that is divisible by $7$ is $F_8=21$

Comment: help? details? please.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, have you understood the link? So, if  integer $r$ divides $F_n,$ it must divide $F_m$ as the notations used in my answer

Answer (score 1):

First you show that the Fibonacci sequence $a_n \mod 7$ is periodic and since $a_8 = 21$ is divisible by 7 you get the result.